# IOS: tableview delegate methods for two tableview

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, delegates

I have these delegate method for a tableview inside a class:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return [array1 count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease] ; 
}

cell.textLabel.text = [array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

if I have a single UITableView it's ok but if I have two UITableView? How Can I organize my code? with tag?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See how all the delegate methods have a `tableView:(UITableView *)tableView` in them?

You can define your table views in the header file and then just simply go: (assuming your table is called `myTable`)

```
if (tableView == myTable)
```

Then you can have as many table views as you like.

So for example:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return [array1 count];
}
```

Becomes:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView == myTable)
    {
       return [array1 count];
    }
    if (tableView == myTable2)
    {
       return [array2 count];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is having your data source act as a table view delegate, instead of your controller.

This is a design more closer to the Model-View-Controller pattern and will allow you much more flexibility and avoid checking for the specific value that the `tableView` argument has got in your delegate methods.

In your case, your delegate/data source would be a class with a member of type `NSArray` and also implementing the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it with tag. Give your UITableViews the tags 1 and 2.

set up an switch:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease] ; 
}

switch ([tableView tag]) {
  case 1:{
    [[cell textLabel] setText:@"First tag"]
    break;
  }
  case 2:{
    [[cell textLabel] setText:@"Second tag"]
    break;
  }
  default:
    break;
}

return cell;
}
```

Comment: Nice usage of the tags, so much easier to handle multiple table

Answer (score 0):

Each of those methods passes in a reference to the table view that's calling it. I usually connect each table to an outlet in interface builder and conditionally return the datasource based on a comparison with tableView in the delegate methods and the outlet names. Doing so with a tag is also possible but messier and more open to complications when editing your view structure.